# How to fix/check the value to NaN?

Tags: javascript

Here i takes an a NaN, how to check/fix it?

```
let findAvareageOfWpm = Math.floor(wordsPerMinute/numberTrains)
```

It' the output into the screen, i need to make if the value of findAvareageOfWpm is NaN, it should return 0

Comment: ternary operator?

Comment: how, pls check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `||` ("logical or") operator:

```js
let findAvareageOfWpm = Math.floor(wordsPerMinute/numberTrains) || 0;
```

- If `Math.floor(wordsPerMinute/numberTrains) == NaN`, then `findAvareageOfWpm` will have the value of whatever comes after `||`. In the example above, it will be `0`.
- If `Math.floor(wordsPerMinute/numberTrains) == 0`, then `findAvareageOfWpm = 0` anyway.
- For any other value, `findAvareageOfWpm = Math.floor(wordsPerMinute/numberTrains)`.

Answer (score 1):

if(!isNaN(wordsPerMinute) && !isNaN(numberTrains)){

let findAvareageOfWpm = Math.floor(wordsPerMinute/numberTrains)
}